# Can I use flat json keys in i18n-js react native

Tags: react-native, translation, i18n-js

I have a flat json as follows

`'action.skip': 'Skip this for now',`

 `'action.start': 'Start'`

I want to call it as

```
{I18n.t('action.start')}
```

currently it is not working because i18n trying to find "action" key and its child "start" instead of "action.start". I couldn't find any option to change the key separator. please help

Answer (score 1):

We can change the key seperator by adding following codes.

```
import I18n from 'i18n-js';

import { de, en } from '../locales';

I18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
I18n.defaultSeparator = '_';
```

i18n-js now only split the string with "_", so if add "abc.xyz" it will treat as a single key.

Comment: is it working ?  for me it's not working.

Comment: did you used only I18n.defaultSeparator = '_', or you have done anything else also. Because for me defaultSeparator not working.

Comment: I have done only this. which character you using for the split?

Comment: I can use any character other than "."  which is default, but it's not working for any character.

Comment: I didn't get you... could you please share your code ?

Comment: [        import I18n from 'i18n-js';


        import EN from "../locales/EN";
        import HIN from "../locales/HIN";

        I18n.translations = {
          EN,
          HIN,
        };

        I18n.defaultLocale = "EN"; // If the current locale in device is not en or hi
        I18n.locale = "EN"; // If we do not want the framework to use the phone's locale by default
        I18n.fallbacks = true
        I18n.missingBehaviour ='guess'

        I18n.defaultSeparator = "/"]

Comment: import I18n from 'i18n-js';

import { de, en } from '../locales';

I18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
I18n.defaultSeparator = '|';

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  de
};

export default I18n;

this is my code

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think there is some issue with the plugin so I changed it to I18next,